# Is it possible for a excel pivot table to gather all data and make it as header?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Like this one:
![[http://screencast.com/t/juLF6N2RKciy]](http://screencast.com/t/juLF6N2RKciy%5d)

I want the table above to be like this one
![[http://screencast.com/t/MdKrUANnZrv9]](http://screencast.com/t/MdKrUANnZrv9%5d)

I hope it make sense, is that possible for a pivot table without any scripts?

Comment: A pivot table would not help you with this type of charting. You would need to manually manipulate the data to get your headers. eg. Copy all titles to one column and use the 'Remove duplicates' option. Then copy and special paste - transpose to your header range.

Comment: @amoy thank you, it seems I need to make some script for this.